# Perl, performance, reading a file

Tags: performance, perl, file

Good morning people, I have some questions to solve... let's see if you can answer my questions.

I have a .txt with nucleotides (fasta file). Each line contains 124 nucleotides, and I need to read codons of 4 nucleotides (yes, actually a codon is made up 3 nucleotides but here I really need to read 4 by 4). So, as 124 is multiple of 4, I don't have problems.

With this loop, I create 5 file outputs within 5 seconds:

```
sub sequence() {
    foreach $line (<SEQ>) {
        next if (index($line, ">") != -1);
        some actions........
```

However, what if each line is not multiple of 4? What if each line has a length of 125 nucleotides? I've tested this mechanism (joining all lines, ignoring the first one):

```
sub sequence() {                        #Joining lines from the sequence.
    $one = "";
    while ($line = <SEQ>) {
        next if (index($line, ">") != -1);
        chomp $line;
        $one .= $line; }
```

But it takes 50 seconds!!! Instead of my initial 5 seconds.

Instead of `$one` in the code above, I've tried as well the following code, but it also takes approximately 50 seconds....

```
$contents = do { local $/;  <SEQ> };
$contents =~ s/\A.*?\n//;
$contents =~ tr/\n//;
```

So, any suggestion to make my script faster if `length($line) % 4 !=0` ???

Thanks!

Comment: You really should profile your code to ascertain where your performance bottlenecks are. I think your alternatives are showing that you are not focusing on the slow part of your code. Perl is quite capable of concatenating thousands of lines in seconds on modern systems. [`Devel::NYTProf`](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::NYTProf) is a popular code-profiling option.

Comment: If you can also clarify where the 124 vs. 125 nucleotides fits in the context of your code snippets as well please...

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, I have just noticed that I tested it reading 3 codons at a time, and did not alter it to your choice of 4, until just now . . . please do double-check you alter your code similarly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is probably growing too long. Try instead of loading the whole string then processing it, to maintain a string buffer of unprocessed text:

- Read in a line to start to a string (let's call it `$remaining_codons`)
- Read next 4 codons (which is code you are not showing), and `remove` them from `$recent_codons`. You could simply do this by having a method from your "do stuff" section that consumed as many codons as possible 4 at a time and returned the remaining 0 to 3 codons.
- Once there are less than 4 codons remaining:

  - Attempt to read a new line or end if not possible
  - Append new line to the remaining items
  - Repeat reading codons 4 at a time

What that might look like re-using your first code structure

```
sub sequence() {
    my $remaining_codons = '';
    foreach $line (<SEQ>) {
        next if (index($line, ">") != -1);
        $remaining_codons = $remaining_codons . $line;
        while ( length($remaining_codons) > 3 ) { 
           my $next_codons = substr( $remaining_codons, 0, 4 ); 
           $remaining_codons = substr( $remaining_codons, 4 ); 
           # Do stuff
        }
```